# Counting the number of consecutive 1's in binary

Tags: python, strings

[hackerrank.com Task](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-binary-numbers):

> Given a base-10 integer, *n*, convert it to binary (base-2). Then find and print the base-10 integer denoting the maximum number of consecutive 1's in *n*'s binary representation.

This question has already been answered but it was in Ruby and I couldn't quite understand the concept, I am just starting to code. What can you suggest me to improve on this piece of code? I think its quite long considering the work it does or is this the efficient solution?

```
count = 0
max_value = 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    binary_num = bin(n).split("b")
    binary_num = binary_num[1]
    print(binary_num)
    for index, i in enumerate(binary_num):
        if i == "1":
            count += 1
            next_item = index + 1 
            while next_item < len(binary_num):           
                if binary_num[next_item] == "1":
                    count += 1
                    counter = count
                    temp = counter                    
                    next_item += 1
                    if temp > max_value:
                        max_value = temp
                else:
                    counter = count                 
                    count = 0 
                    break
        if next_item == (len(binary_num)):
            break

    print("count is =",max_value)
```

Comment: Your instinct is quite right. There is no *need* to convert numbers to strings in order to work with binary. The trap that you and most of other answers (included the accepted one) fall in, is not knowing how to work with binary numbers. See Anatolii's answer for what the normal, more efficient (albeit very commonly unknown) approach is.

Comment: This task is a good exercise, but since people re bringing up efficiency, I think it's worth mentioning that newer processors have this [built in to the hardware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE4#POPCNT_and_LZCNT).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The whole idea is achievable with a few lines of code and based on designating segments of **`1`** 's items (repeated consecutive sequence) using **`0`** segments as separators.
See the concise solution below:

```
def find_max_ones(num):
    if not num:
        return 0
    bin_num = bin(num)[2:]
    print(bin_num)
    return len(max(bin_num.replace('0', ' ').split(), key=len))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    num = int(input('Enter integer number:'))
    max_ones = find_max_ones(num)
    print("max 1's count is", max_ones)
```

Sample usage:

```
Enter integer number:1000
1111101000
max 1's count is 5
```

Comment: I know this is not meant to be codegolfed, but your return line can be written shorter as `return len(max(bin_num.split('0')))`

Comment: @Zchpyvr, I would not consider that as better approach. Consider this case: `bin(18888889)[2:].split('0')` that generates `['1', '', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '111', '', '', '1', '111', '', '1']` , a list of **16** items for further traversal. While the former approach returns a list of 6 items.

Comment: Sure, although all the extra items are empty strings. Assuming the empty strings create extra overhead, what would you think of using `re`: `max(re.split(r'0+', bin(18888889)[2:]))`?

Comment: Or at least can we agree that `key=len` is not necessary?

Comment: using `re`: `max(re.split(r'0+', bin(18888889)[2:]))`. >> it's  harder to read. If no performance gain, code should aim for maximal readability. Code is a _human_ machine interface after all

Comment: @Poutrathor My profiler gives me a 100x speed improvement. But I do agree with readability.

Comment: Compared to @roman 's answer? That's a nice improvement

Comment: @Zchpyvr, Why telling people "fairy tails" about **100**x speed improvement? Your approach is slower: `In [56]: %timeit len(max(bin(18888889000)[2:].replace('0', ' ').split(), key=len))                                           
1.74 µs ± 160 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)` - 
`In [57]: %timeit len(max(re.split(r'0+', bin(18888889000)[2:])))                                                             
4.26 µs ± 196 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
`

Comment: @Poutrathor, I would not believe in every comment saying 100x or 1000x speedups - it's better to check it out for yourself to find the truth. See the above comment with timings. Critical thinking is an advantage.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Oh :) I did not believe him (nor do I believe you, yet). I merely wrote a polite answer awaiting the time I could test it myself and asking "compared to" [which implementation] such an improvement was measured. For one, you tested only one number 188888889000.

Comment: My bad, I must've misread 'ns' as 'μs'. I apologize for that.

Comment: My comments about the other points remain valid, however. There are a lot of simple ways to improve this answer that are better in terms of readability and performance. Even using `.split('0')` is more performant and easier to read than your answer. But if you want to ignore me based on an error on my part about speed, then I understand. I just wanted to suggest some edits.

Comment: @Zchpyvr, Admitting faults is a strong human quality.

Comment: @Zchpyvr: I'd recommend posting your own answer with a focus on performance, where you'll have room to show a fast version and prove your points about what's faster for what kinds of input numbers (fits in 32 bits; huge; a few long runs of ones, alternating zeros and ones).  I suspect that expanding a number into a list of base-2 digits at all is relatively slow, and I seem to recall a solution for this involving a bitwise trick.  But maybe only in C where you don't have Python interpreter overhead, and maybe involving popcount or bitscan (`__builtin_ctz()` count trailing zeros)

Comment: @Zchpyvr The author wasn't asking about the highest performance solution anyways. This one is good enough as it's easy to understand, it has a linear time complexity (in regard to binary digits) and the author also accepted it.

Comment: @Zchpyvr: Ah right, Anatolii's answer was what I was remembering: iterate `x &= x << 1;` until `x` becomes zero, counting the iterations.  It's not O(1), just O(result), but doesn't involve any bit-scan.

Comment: Using strings to manipulate numbers strikes me as incredibly inelegant.

Answer (score 21):

> I think its quite long considering the work it does

Your instinct is right - it's quite long. It can be implemented with much fewer lines of code, especially in **Python**. A solution from @RomanPerekhrest highlights it quite well.

> is this the efficient solution?

From the time complexity prospective, it's not an efficient solution. It's O(n<sup>2</sup>), where `n` - number of binary digits in your number. Why? Because in your outer loop, you process each digit one by one regardless of the results in your inner loop. So, if your inner loop finds a segment of ones you don't move `ì` and `index` to a bit position following this segment. Instead, you pick a second bit in this segment and find the same segment without the first bit again.

For instance, let's say we have a number which binary representation is `111110`. Then your algorithm will find the following segments of ones:

```
11111  | 4 inner loop steps
 1111  | 3 inner loop steps
  111  | 2 inner loop steps
   11  | 1 inner loop steps
    1  | 0 inner loop steps
```

An optimal solution has a O(n) time complexity. I'll leave it up to you to update your code based on the explanation above.

**Bonus**

I noticed that each answer uses `bin()` to calculate the longest segment of ones. However, it's not really needed since this approach has an additional `O(n)` space complexity (as you recall it from the previous paragraph, `n` - number of binary digits).

We could just use bitwise operators to achieve the same result. For example, let's say there's a number `1100011101`. It has `3` separate segments of ones: Now, let's play a bit - we will calculate a left shifted version of `x` and then perform bitwise `AND` on it. Then, for the shifted version we will calculate its left shifted number and so on.

```
1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0  (x)
         &
1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0  (x << 1)
---------------------
1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0  y = ((x) & (x << 1))


1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0  (y)
         & 
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0  (y << 1)
---------------------
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0  z = ((y) & (y << 1))


0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0  (z)
         & 
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0  (z << 1)
---------------------
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  ((z) & (z << 1))
```

So, as you can see it took us `3` steps to reach `0`. But `3` is also the length of the longest segment of ones. And it's not a coincidence because bitwise `AND` of a number and its shifted version shortens each segment of ones by `1`. Hence, the longest segment will lose all its ones after < length of the longest segment of ones > steps.

**Code**

```
def find_max_ones(number):
    maxLength = 0

    while number > 0:
        left_shifted_number = number << 1
        number = number & left_shifted_number
        maxLength += 1

    return maxLength


if __name__ == '__main__':
    number = int(input('Enter integer number:'))
    max_ones = find_max_ones(number)

    print("Length of the longest segment is ", str(max_ones))
```

Answer (score 15):

This is a good opportunity to learn two things, separation of concerns and the standard library module `itertools`.

You have three separate issues, each of which you can put into their own function:

1. Take input from the user
2. Turn it into a sequence of `0` and `1`.
3. Find the longest run of `1`.

For the user input it can be as simple as your one line, or slightly more sophisticated as this function:

```
def ask_user(message="", type_=str):
    while True:
        try:
            return type_(input(message))
        except ValueError:
            print("wrong type, try again")
```

Later you might want to add things like validator functions, allowed ranges, etc, but this should suffice for now.

Turning the number into a binary sequence is easy:

```
def to_binary(n):
    return bin(n)[2:]
```

Or even like this, as mentioned in the comments by Eric:

```
def to_binary(x):
    return format(x, "b")
```

And for the last step you can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

def longest_run_of(it, value):
    return max(len(list(group))
               for c, group in groupby(it)
               if c == value)
```

Putting it all together, using some `f-string` for slightly easier string formatting:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = ask_user("Enter a number: ", int)
    n_bin = to_binary(n)
    longest_run = longest_run_of(n_bin, "1")
    print(f"count is = {longest_run}")
```

Once you are this far it becomes a lot easier to try and test different implementations, as you can change (and test) each part individually. At this point it might make sense to start profiling to see which implementation is the fastest, depending on your needs.

Comment: `to_binary = '{:b}'.format` is simpler than using `bin` to add `0b` then removing it again. `to_binary = lambda x: format(x, 'b')` also works, and avoids some string parsing.

Comment: @Eric What about `def to_binary(x): return f'{x:b}'`?

Comment: @SolomonUcko Directly invoking `format` might be better, because it does not need to parse the f-string. Some profiling would be needed there as well, though. In addition, it means requiring Python 3.6, which may or may not be a concern.

Comment: @Graipher Aren't f-strings are parsed at compile time? I'll investigate more when I get a chance.

Comment: @Graipher At least for me, f-strings result in direct usage of the `FORMAT_VALUE` bytecode instruction, instead of loading and calling `format`, which uses `LOAD_GLOBAL` then `CALL_FUNCTION`, which is almost certainly *significantly* slower.

Comment: @SolomonUcko Fair enough, I was not at a PC, so could not directly check myself.

Comment: @Graipher Makes sense. (Frankly, you don't technically *need* a computer if you can use something like Termux, a terminal emulator, or some sort of Python app instead, but it is significantly easier on an actual computer with an actual keyboard and stuff.)

Answer (score 5):

I am a newbie to coding myself, but your logic is kind of hard to follow - probably my problem. You should use slicing operation on the string to get the '0b' removed from `bin()` function result as i feel like a cleaner method.

Here's an alternate logic I came up with

```
count = 0
final_count = 0
concecutive_check = False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    bin_representation = bin(n)[2:] #slice operation to remove 'ob'
    print(bin_representation)

    for num in bin_representation:
        if concecutive_check and num == '1':
            count +=1
        elif concecutive_check and num == '0':
            concecutive_check = False
            if count > final_count:
                final_count = count
            count = 0
        elif num == '1':
            concecutive_check = True
            count = 1

    if count > final_count: # final check just in case the binary string ends in 1 and doesn't trigger the above if statements
        final_count = count
    print(f'{final_count} max sequence count')
```

As general coding practices, comments where appropriate would be good (as in if something is understandable from the name of the function or object it doesn't need a comment), or if there is a nonsensical aspect like my second `count > final count` check, explaining the reason for that.

Another thing i noticed is you using the `enumerate` operation without really using the index for anything beyond as a counter for loop... why? wouldn't the generic for loop over iterable take care of that?

I think the logic route you used is a bit round about way of doing it, a single boolean state variable and two int variable is all you need to keep track of the longest count over the string.

Answer (score 4):

A few improvements following principles of *Cleancode* and *Divide & Conquer*:

1. Split into small tasks, each one a function.
2. Use meaningful names.
3. Leverage the language's power.

#### Split into small tasks, each one a function

The challenge's description *explicitly* names 2 tasks, thus implemented in **functions**:

1. `convert_to_binary(number)`
2. `max_consecutive_1s_of_binary(binary)`

Above functions already have **meaningful names** (see 2), expressing *what* they do.

Besides you have other tasks, given *implicitly*:

1. Read a (decimal) number from STDIN
2. Determine length of a sequence (of max consecutive 1s)
3. Print number to STDOUT (length of max consecutive 1s)

These side-tasks can be implemented using existing functions (in Python).

#### Use meaningful names

From above functional design you can derive **data-structures and variables**. Name them to express *what* (in context of your program) they contain:

1. `number_input`
2. `binary_representation`
3. `max_consecutive_1s`
4. `length_of_max_consecutive_1s`

#### Leverage the language's power

Use already built-in functions where suitable:

1. Use [`bin` and **slicing**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395356/how-can-i-make-bin30-return-00011110-instead-of-0b11110) for stripping of the *binary marker*; or use [`format(number, 'b')`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699866/python-int-to-binary-string) directly
2. [**string-splitting** by regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13209288/python-split-string-based-on-regex) for split the binary representation into *consecutive 1s* using `0` as split-marker (very smart [solution by Roman](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/234626))
3. **max** for finding the maximum of a list based on some *key criterion* (here the length)

#### See also

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37605328/calculating-consecutive-1s-in-a-binary-number
- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-consecutive-ones-or-zeros-in-a-binary-array/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the other programming languages but it's quite easy to implement this particular program using inbuilt functions.
So here is my code:

```py
from itertools import groupby  
def output(n):  
    binary_num = bin(n).replace("0b","")  
    print(max(len(list(group)) for i,group in groupby(binary_num) if i== '1'))  


if __name__ == '__main__':  
    n = int(input())  
    output(n)
```

Comment: Usually alternative implementations are not considered valid answers if they don't contain a review. After all, this is Code *Review*, not Code *Alternatives*. However, since you specifically move toward in-built functions and your code is much shorter, the review is implied. But please keep that in mind next time. Welcome to Code Review!

Comment: Do note that if I ever find constructs like yours in production code, I'd delete it outright. That last line of your `output` function is abysmal. There is way too much happening on a single line, hurting readability and maintainability. If you go the route of oneliners, perhaps putting it in some kind of generator function would be more appropriate.